# Int php variables by mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have people logging into my website. How do I use their username (column) to initialize their variables in their mysql row to use in other php files?

Here is my log in form:

```
<?
/*Use of Sessions*/
if(!session_id())
session_start();

header("Cache-control: private"); //avoid an IE6 bug (keep this line on top of the page)

$login='NO data sent';

/*simple checking of the data*/
if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{

/*Connection to database logindb using your login name and password*/
$db=mysql_connect('host','username','pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db');

/*additional data checking and striping*/
$_POST['login']=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['login'])));
$_POST['pass']=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['pass'])));
$_POST['pass']=md5($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['pass']=strrev($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['pass']=md5($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['pass'].=$_POST['pass'];
$_POST['pass']=md5($_POST['pass']);


$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='{$_POST['login']}' AND password='{$_POST['pass']}'",$db) or die(mysql_error());

/*If there is a matching row*/
if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
    $login='Welcome back, '.$_SESSION['login'];
    $login.='</br> we are redirecting you.';
echo $login;
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL=/php/learn/selectone.php">';    
    exit;    

    }
else
{
    $login= 'Wrong login or password';
}

mysql_close($db);

}

//you may echo the data anywhere in the file
echo $login;

?>
```

How do I get the rest of their information. Like I have a column for their first name, it's called fname. How would i get that?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: **Do not use MD5 to hash passwords**.  Using it multiple times backwards and forwards isn't any better.  Use bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: i didn't post to be critisized.... i just want my question to be answered please.

Answer (score 0):

So you stored the username in a `$_SESSION` variable. In the other pages, you would check whether `$_SESSION['login']` is set, and if it is, load whatever info about the username you want from the database.

```
// If user is logged on,
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    // .. load user's data from the database
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='{$_SESSION['login']}'");
}
```

I wouldn't advise storing only the username in the $_SESSION variable, unless you make sure no two users can have the same name.